# Proving set theory is true if an argument has been given

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having troubles finding a proof for a set.

$$A^C \cup (B-C)^C = ((A \cap B) - C)^C$$

I have tried drawing a diagram to represent both and help to find a proof for it but in all honesty I cannot figure it out and need some help understanding the problem.

Comment: The title of the question is obscure and it seems to have no relation to the text of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Using the definition of the set difference and the DeMorgan law we have

$$A^C \cup (B-C)^C =A^C\cup \left(B\cap C^C\right)^C=A^C\cup B^C\cup \left(C^C\right)^C=A^C\cup B^C\cup C.$$

and
$$\left((A \cap B) - C\right)^C=\left(A\cap B\cap C^C\right)^C=A^C\cup B^C\cup C.$$

By this the equivalence has been proven.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is a bit peculiar. You understand that the problem here is NOT to "prove set theory is true", don't you?

The most Basic way to prove "$X= Y$", for X and Y sets, is to prove both "$X\subset Y$" and "$Y\subset X$".  And to prove "$X\subset Y$", start "if $x\in X$" and use the definitions of X and Y to conclude "then $x \in Y$".

Here, $X= A^C\cup(B- C)^C$ so saying "x\in X" means that either $x\in A^C$ or $x\in (B- C)^C$.

If $x\in A^C$ then x is NOT in A so NOT in $A\cap B$ so NOT in $(A\cap B- C$ so that $x\in (A\cap B- C)^C$.

```
If $x\in (B- C)^C$ then x is NOT in B- C so x is NOT in B or x is in C.
```

If x is not in B, then it is not in $A\cap B$ so is not in $A\cap B- C$ so **is** in $(A\cap B- C)^C$.
If x is in C, then it is not in $A\cap B- C$ so is in $(A\cap B- C)^c$.

That proves that $A^C\cup (B- C)^C\subset (A\cap B- C)^C$.  Now try proving the other way yourself.

(By the way, it is not a good idea to use "C" to mean both a set and "complement".  If you are using "C" as a set, use the lower case, "c", to indicate the complement.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the universal set containing $A,B$ and $C$. Then,

$A^C \cup (B-C)^C=(X-A) \cup (X-(B-C))$

$=X-(A \cap (B-C))$ ....(By De-Morgan's Law).

$=X-(A \cap (B \cap C^C))$

$=X-((A \cap B) \cap C^C)$......(By Associativity).

$=X-((A \cap B)-C)$

$=((A \cap B)-C)^C.$